# js function doesn't work with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, html, json

whats wrong with this code? when i click on button it shows undefined before first array value:

```js
function loadDoc() {
  var x;
  var edare = JSON.parse('{"names":["ali", "mansour", "taghi"]}');
  for (var i in edare.names) {
    x += edare.names[i] + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="loadDoc();" value="test">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I vote to **close** this since the title clearly doesn't represent the actually problem

Comment: ok. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `x` variable's initial value is `undefined`. So when you try to concatenate with another string it does `undefined + string`.

To fix this, you should give an initialize value to your variable:

```
var x = "";
```

Also, you should use `for` loops instead of `for...in` for arrays. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) for more information.

And finally, should also move your `.innerHTML = x;` outside of the loop to prevent updating the DOM on every iteration.

```
var x = "";
var edare = JSON.parse('{"names":["ali", "mansour", "taghi"]}');

for (var i=0; i<edare.names.length; i++) {
    x += edare.names[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

Comment: And to not change the DOM for every element in the array move the line with `.innerHTML = x` after the loop (and `for ( ... in ...)` is for objects, `for (...; ...; ...)` for arrays)

Comment: "And finally, should also move your .innerHTML = x; outside of the loop to prevent updating the DOM on every iteration.' This is especially important, as every update to the DOM is extremely expensive.  If there's a few hundred items in the array, this can cause numerous seconds of end user lag while the DOM is being written out.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your array properly:

```
var i, nameConcat = "";
for(i=0; i < edare.names.length; i++){
    nameConcat += edare.names[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = nameConcat;
```

Or:

```
var concatNames = "";
edare.names.forEach(function(name){
    nameConcat += name + "<br>";
});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = nameConcat;
```

Comment: @NavidM: This doesn't actually work. It's ultimately going to have only the last value in the list.

Comment: @rockstar You're right, fixed to match what OP output.

Comment: This also has the same issue as the original code because you didn't initialize `nameConcat` to an empty string. You'll also want to fix your second example where you forgot to change `edare.names[i]` to `name`. Lastly, the quotation marks for your `br` tag are inside the angle brackets instead of outside.

Comment: ...the `<br>` should also be in the loop. I submitted an edit to fix the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.reduce()` to construct a single string from the array of strings.

That way you only need to set the `.innerHTML` once.

```js
function loadDoc() {
  const edare = JSON.parse('{"names":["ali", "mansour", "taghi"]}');

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = edare.names.reduce((s, itm) =>
    s + itm + "<br>"
  , "")
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="loadDoc();" value="test">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Or just `.join()` the list.

```js
function loadDoc() {
  const edare = JSON.parse('{"names":["ali", "mansour", "taghi"]}');

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = edare.names.join("<br>");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="loadDoc();" value="test">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Only difference here is that there's no trailing `<br>` at the end, but you can easily add that in if you really want it.

Answer (score 0):

but it works with this:

```
function loadDoc() {
var x="";
var edare = JSON.parse ('{"names":["ali", "mansour", "taghi"]}');
for (var i in edare.names) {
    x += edare.names[i] + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
}
```